# Android FTP app that preserves timestamps

Tags: ftp, android-app

I want to use an FTP app to preserve folder and file timestamps from Android to PC.

Is there any Android FTP app that preserves the date modified of files and folders?

Comment: Have you try Total Commander? I can't test it but I see this software have plenty of options.

Comment: I've tried total commander, but the ftp plugin says to connect to hostname, I tried to use the pixel 7's wifi address and my PC's wifi address and both of them didn't work. I'm not sure how to use FTP from total commander