# Android FTP server app that preserves original date modified of files and folders?

Tags: android, time-management, ftp, directories, file-sharing

Most FTP server apps on the google play store don't preserve the date modified of folders and files but I want to preserve them with FTP. I've tried:

1. Wifi FTP server (https://play.google.com/store/search?q=wifi%20FTP%20server&c=apps)
2. SSH Sever (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.xnano.android.sshserver),
3. solid explorer (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.solidexplorer2)
4. FTP server pro (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.theolivetree.ftpserverpro)

All of them give me folder and file timestamps in something what appears to be in UTC.

For example, a picture on my pixel 7 with filename:PXL_20230512_220328833.jpg (pic of me and my mom at the airport). The time is displayed in UTC after the '_' which is 22:03:28 UTC which in North America is UTC-4 in summer time = 18:03:28 = 6:03:28 PM on May 12, 2023 which is correct because that's what pixel does.

When FTP server is mounted on Windows 10 file explorer, the date modified shows up as may 11, 2023 @ 8:00 PM. What is going on here? It's not just one file, its over 100+ files taken during May 13..May 16, 2023. Is there any FTP server app which preserves the original date and time of the source files and folders inside Android?

Comment: Is this the same question? https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/88425/android-ftp-app-that-preserves-timestamps

Comment: Have you tried other FTP clients? May be the problem is not the server but the client? What time zone is your Windows configured to? Note that FTP seems to be unaware of time zones at all. On your Pixel what app do you use to see the date? Are you sure the date is the file-date and not the exif-date?

Comment: @jmizv oh yeah it is the same question, sorry I hadn't realized I posted that question

I'm finding it difficult to understand what the difference is between client/server because some android FTP apps don't start a "Server" that auto assigns a ip and port while others ask to join "hostname" and port..so like..how do I use these diff clients with windows? Im in UTC-5 EST timezone US & Canada ...in my pixel 7, I can see the original date modified in the files app or any other file browser. Yes, I'm sure its the file-date not the exif date taken of any video/picture/document.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android FTP app that preserves timestamps](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/88425/android-ftp-app-that-preserves-timestamps)